# How to use R apply without changing a function

Tags: r, apply

I have a basic character date to `POSIXct` function

```
charDateToPosixct <- function(chrDate, format, timeZone) {
    as.POSIXct(chrDate, format=format, tz=timeZone)
}
```

I have a data frame with date as character and timezone.

```
chrDate <- c("4/25/2012","4/24/2012","4/16/2012","6/30/2012")
timeZone <- c("US/Eastern","US/Central","US/Pacific","US/Eastern")
df <- data.frame(date=chrDate,timezone=timeZone)
str(df)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ date    : Factor w/ 4 levels "4/16/2012","4/24/2012",..: 3 2 1 4
 $ timezone: Factor w/ 3 levels "US/Central","US/Eastern",..: 2 1 3 2
```

I want to change the data type of date to `POSIXct` and so want to apply this function `charDateToPosixct` to each row with the format `"%m/%d/%y"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an anonymous function in `apply` like this

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) charDateToPosixct(x[1], "%m/%d/%y", x[2]))
#[1] 1587787200 1587704400 1587020400 1593489600
```

**edit**

You could convert the numeric vector you got using `apply` to `POSIXct`

```
as.POSIXct(apply(df, 1, function(x) charDateToPosixct(x[1], "%m/%d/%y", x[2])), origin='1970-01-01')
[1] "2020-04-25 05:00:00 CDT" "2020-04-24 06:00:00 CDT" "2020-04-16 08:00:00 CDT" "2020-06-30 05:00:00 CDT"
```

Or, you can use `lapply` to get a list of `POSIXct` objects.  Then you can combine with `do.call` `c`, or `Reduce` (You have to use `as.character` because you implicitly used `stringsAsFactors=TRUE` when you created the `data.frame`)

```
do.call(c, lapply(seq_len(NROW(df)), function(i) {
  charDateToPosixct(as.character(df$date[i]), "%m/%d/%Y", as.character(df$timezone[i]))
}))
```

Or, if you have 2 vectors, you don't even need the `data.frame`

```
do.call(c, lapply(seq_along(chrDate), function(i) {
    charDateToPosixct(chrDate[i], "%m/%d/%Y", timeZone[i])
}))
```

Or, using `Reduce`

```
Reduce(c, lapply(seq_along(chrDate), function(i) {
    charDateToPosixct(chrDate[i], "%m/%d/%Y", timeZone[i])
}))
```

My timezone is CDT, so any of the above give me

```
[1] "2012-04-24 23:00:00 CDT" "2012-04-24 00:00:00 CDT" "2012-04-16 02:00:00 CDT" "2012-06-29 23:00:00 CDT"
```

Comment: if i use df$date1 <- apply(...) it doesn't change the data type to posixct. str(df$date1) is still numeric and not posixct.

Comment: That's the way `apply` works. My results match the results you get using the workaround that you said works.

Comment: The 2nd part of the question where i said Alternatively or workaround was wrong and so i omitted. sorry 4 the confusion.

Comment: From `?apply` in the *Value* section (i.e. the section that tells you what the function returns): "the result is coerced by ‘as.vector’ to one of the basic vector types before the dimensions are set".  So, that's why you get a vector of class `numeric` instead of `POSIXct`

Comment: thanks. Is there a better way if i remove the constraints of calling the same function ? The function is currently getting invoked N times.

Comment: I don't think so since you have different timezones.  There are other ways to hide the loop, e.g. `as.POSIXct(Vectorize("charDateToPosixct")(chrDate, "%m/%d/%y", timeZone), origin='1970-01-01')`